# Como criar uma tabela com HTML e CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá.

Como faço para criar uma tabela responsiva em html e css usando < ul> ou < table> desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Comece criando a estrutura HTML com os elementos `table`, `tr` e `td`. Depois, tente estilizada com CSS. Se não der certo, você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar todos esses códigos que você fez, explicando como ficou e como você gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: http://www.leandroguarino.com.br/index.php?p=curso_html5_css&aula=tabelas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código HTML para criar esta tabela, seria o seguinte:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-responsive">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td width="100" rowspan="2">Resumo</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>7</td>   
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><b>Direto</b></td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><b>1 Parada</b></td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero ter ajudado.